# Walking through C++ code on paper, how would you do it?

Tags: c++

In my programming class, we have tests and quizzes based on code samples that we must walk through and determine the final output. Usually they are tricky pieces of code and by the time I realize, I'm stuck in some random function and have no idea what I'm doing.

How do you properly run through code on paper? Keeping track of loops, variables, functions, everything, it's confusing to me.

For example, here is a past quiz we had, which I got 100% on but it took me forever and was very messy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class foo {
     char word[20];
     int qty;

public:
     foo( ) { set(3, 5); }

     foo( int m, const char * s) { set(m, m+1);
                                   strcpy(word, s);       }

     foo(  const foo& a ) { cout << "... hahaha.1" << endl;
                qty = 3 + a.qty;
                strcpy( word, a.word );
                strcat( word, ".5.6.7" );
                cout << "... hahah.2" << endl;  }

     ~foo( ) { cout << qty << "," << word << "!!!" << endl; }

     void set(int a, int b){ qty = a + b;
                             strcpy( word, "summer" ); }
     void wow();

     void output(){ cout << word << "," << qty << endl;  }
};

void hello( foo& );
void greet( foo );

int main() {

     foo x, y(100, "QUIZ");

     greet( y );
     cout << "a.b.c.d.e." << endl;

     hello( x );
     x.output();
     y.output();

     cout << "...the end" << endl;
     return 0;
}

void foo::wow() { strcat(word,".1.2.3");
                  qty += 4;     }

void greet( foo g ) { cout << "...HI.1\n";
                      g.wow(); 
                      g.output(); 
                      cout << "...HI.2\n"; }


void hello(foo & h) {  cout << "...hello.1" << endl;
                foo e;

                e = h;
                h.wow();
                h.output();
                e.output();
                cout << "...hello.2\n"; }
```

Comment: It's hard to know what to say beyond "read it and understand it."

Comment: Practice, practice, practice...

Comment: Take notes, annotate parts of code directly, split code into smaller pieces, draw call trees/graphs, draw state machines, expand/collapse call trees/graphs' detail level so you can see what's relevant and can't see what's not. Keep track of your progress so you don't fall into an endless loop yourself repeating the same work over and over again. :) And yes, practice, practice and practice.

Comment: The worst kind are crawling through recursive functions gosh..

Comment: I think just saying "practice" is not particularly useful, as I'm sure different people use different approaches. For me, the first step is always understanding what main function does. Especially when dealing with legacy code, where large chunk of codebase may no longer be doing anything or deals with extremely rare scenarios. Once you understand what main does (in this case it doesn't care about passed parameters, prints some characters on screen and always returns 0), you can drill down in individual parts. On paper you can use highlighter to group relevant bits together, like foo:wow decl.

Comment: Closing this wasn't right tbh, the question got a fair number of upvotes in short time, so there were people interested in answers.\

Comment: @MikeTrusov Mike, everything except innate reflexes is a learned skill. You may not realize it, but as you do more and more in-depth code analysis/reviews, you expand your abilities, you start recognizing stuff (algorithms/logic) quicker, you start seeing bugs quicker. Riding a bicycle, playing a piano, speaking a language, solving math problems, programming, etc, ad infinitum, it's all learned.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I don't disagree that people generally get better at things when they practice. However, there are multiple ways of learning, and different approaches may be more suitable for different areas for different people: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_styles (not specific to programming). I don't know enough about learning to accurately classify the approach I take when understanding code, but I'm sure there are people who could manage achieve better understanding of the same problem quicker by approaching the problem differently.

Comment: @MikeTrusov Re `I don't disagree that people generally get better at things when they practice` but that's the whole point. You first learn (somehow) the basics and then perhaps you learn some more but you constantly improve in the process. You will be able to keep more things in your head simultaneously, access and recall the learned methods and ideas quicker and view code at different levels of abstraction.

Comment: @MikeTrusov Many problems can be solved top-down, bottom-up, by trial and error and in a number of other ways at the same time. You can learn those too and over time you can build a pretty accurate gut feeling as to what may be the best approach. That comes with practice, with past experience.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Indeed, after the OP looks at 1000 of similar problems he'll eventually figure out his own best way, however that would take time. Instead he's asking people with experience to figure out what the majority thinks would make his life easier while he learns.

Comment: @MikeTrusov You may make some things easier with tools, with check lists and with discipline. However, one must make mistakes and overcome ever-bigger obstacles to truly learn and advance. So, the only universal advice would be to persevere, to try, to fall and rise, and to think long-term.

Answer (score 0):

Practise is the best way to understand code. When i'm trying to do exercise like this, i'm not trying to understand all the functions at the beginning. I'm starting from main and just go like debbuger line by line watching all the variables. If sth is confusing you, just write all variables on paper and mark their every change. However there is no way to learn reading and understanding code better and faster than training.

Answer (score 0):

"Think like a computer"

You have a program and data the program is using.

You need to know where abouts in the program you are up to. This really needs to be a stack since when you call a method you have to know where to come back to when the method ends.

You need to keep track of each variable - of course variables can be local to a method call, so these are really a stack too, and that is where you have to be really careful to make sure you are changing the right instance of a local variable.
Global variables are easy since there is only one copy, so you can put them in your stack, but just down the bottom.

To work on paper, it's easiest to put the bottom of the stack at the top of the page and grow the stack downwards.  Remember that when a method returns, it's local variables no longer exist, so rub them out or mark the top of the stack in some way.

Things get even more fun if you are doing any multi threading...